# PHP/Apache Questions

Tags: php, apache

I am a beginner web developer looking to create a website using PHP, MySQl, and Apache. Windows 10 is downloaded on my laptop. Which version of PHP and which version of Apache should I download? I already have MySQL installed. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The current version is Apache 2.4, PHP 7. That is not a programming question, it would be better targeted at software recommendations.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Passive Aggressive! Appreciate it bud!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use WampServer.

> WampServer is a Windows web development environment. It allows you to
>   create web applications with Apache2, PHP and a MySQL database.
>   Alongside, PhpMyAdmin allows you to manage easily your databases.

Pls download from official [site](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

Comment: Thank you Muhammed! Very much appreciated!